# How to use a function generating an image?

Tags: php, function, image

I have a php code which generate an gif-image defined by a set of parameters. I wrote this code as a function and now I want to insert an image into a html page.

My problem is that whenever I use an img tag I need to specify a name of the file containing an image but I do not have an image in a file. The file containing a function for generation of an image do not contain the image it contain the function generating an image.

I could use a file which would contain an image but then I do not know how to pass parameters to this file. Usage of $_GET does not seem to be a good solution since one of the arguments of the function is a big array.

Is there an elegant solution of the described problem?

Comment: How params in the does the image generation script require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usage of $_GET does not seem to be a good solution since one of the arguments of the function is a big array.

You could `serialize()` the array with your parameters and store it in a temporary file with a randomly generated ID. You would then pass that ID to the image file:

```
<img src="script.php?data=1230491039202439">
```

if you do the creating operation in the script that creates the HTML containing the image reference **before** outputting the `img` tag, this will be safe to do.

The other approach would be generating all images in a separate process, and writing them out into a file (the file name consisting e.g. of the `md5()` value of the serialized data array). This would effectively be a caching solution, where no calculations are made during the time of the request. This may or may not be feasible for you, depending on your project's architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP file that generates the image you need from the specified `$_GET` arguments. In the `<img ... />` tag, you can set the image source to the PHP file path that is passed the proper arguments. In the PHP script, be sure to set the `content-type` header information correctly.

Comment: His problem is that he has more parameters than fit into `$_GET`.